# In hashes key duplicated join the Value into the previous keys in perl script

Tags: perl, hash

```
my %colorfigshash = ();
my $tempcnt = <DATA>;
while($tempcnt=~m/Placement of Figure (?:[^\{]*)\{([^\{\}]*)\} Page ([^\n]*)\n/sg)
{
    $colorfigshash{$1} = $2;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%colorfigshash;

__DATA__
Placement of Figure \hbox {10.7} Page 216
Pages in Color: 216
Placement of Figure \hbox {10.7} Page 217
Pages in Color: 217
```

Current Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      '10.7' => '216'
    };
```

Expected Output

```
$VAR1 = {
      '10.7' => '216-217'
    };
```

How could we merge the values with previous one if the keys are duplicated.
If the Keys duplicated the last Value stored in the hashes table. Anyone could give a path to solve also it would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't your current output `10.7' => '217` ?

Comment: `$VAR1 = {
          '10.7' => '216'
        };`

Comment: Strategy is to push the values onto an array indexed by `$1`.  Then you can process the values in the array to produce a friendlier string.  You can `push @{ $colorfigshash{ $1 } }, $2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a hash of arrays, and re-write it along these lines:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %colorfigshash;

while(<DATA>) { 
    chomp; 
    next unless /^Placement/;
    my ($placement) = /\{(\d+\.\d+)\}/;
    my ($page) = /Page (\d+)/;
    push @{$colorfigshash{$placement}}, $page;
}

for (keys %colorfigshash){
    print "$_ ";
    print join ('-', @{$colorfigshash{$_}}), "\n";
}

__DATA__
Placement of Figure \hbox {10.7} Page 216
Pages in Color: 216
Placement of Figure \hbox {10.7} Page 217
Pages in Color: 217
```

---

```
10.7 216-217
```